# PHP Fetch current page name without extension?

Tags: php

I want to show the current pages filename as the page title, but without the extension. And if possible, the first character should be capitalized. Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Everyone loves one-liners:

```
ucfirst(pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME))
```

The second argument to `pathinfo()` strips the path and extension from the file name (PHP >= 5.2)

Btw, I'm using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead of `__FILE__` because otherwise it would break if the code is ran from another file ;-)

Comment: Yeah, noticed that with a similar solution. So, this is located at nav.php, but I need the title from a file similar to kalvot.php.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen not sure what you mean .. does this work for you, not work for you? can't tell :/

Comment: So, a page in my project consist of 3 pages: nav.php containerpage.php and footer.php . However, every page should have a different title, and placing this script to nav.php would only echo `Nav`, right? I need it to echo Containerpage :)

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen that's what my code does ... it uses `PHP_SELF` which is roughly what can be seen in the location bar of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it, but you may want to do some extra parsing for spaces. However, this is the simplest way, and directly according to your instructions.

```
echo '<title>';
echo ucwords(str_replace('.php', '', __FILE__));
echo '</title>';
```

What I did here is to get the **FILE** constant which is the name of the file being executed. Find the .php extension and replace it with blank (assuming '.php' doesn't occur anywhere else in the filename).

Function ucwords() capitalizes the first letter of substrings separated by spaces.

If you want to do further parsing for spaces, you'll need to recognize the format of your file names and do string replacements/regex accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go from `script.php` to `Script`, yes:

```
// pathinfo give info about given file and returns it into an associative array:
$info = pathinfo( __FILE__ );

// the filename key holds file name without extension nor parent path:
$title = ucwords( $info['filename'] );
```

Comment: Okay, this prints `Nav` which is one part of the page template, containing `head` and navigation. However, I need to return the name of the container script.

Comment: how? `<title>` in body would cause a validation error, and using `<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>` in the head part and then writing that snippet to script that is listed after it wont print anything.

Comment: Then we need to know more about your program structure, edit your question please.

Answer (score 1):

For the first letter needs to be Capitalized, use `ucfirst()`. That is the Uppercase First character function. You can also use `ucwords()` for uppercased words.

To get the filename minus the extenseion, use the [`pathinfo()` funciton](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

```
$path_parts = pathinfo(__FILE__);

echo ucfirst($path_parts['filename']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible:

```
<?php
$page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // Get script filename without any path information
$page = str_replace( array( '.php', '.htm', '.html' ), '', $page ); // Remove extensions
$page = str_replace( array('-', '_'), ' ', $page); // Change underscores/hyphens to spaces
$page = ucwords( $page ); // uppercase first letter of every word

echo "This title is: $page";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 scripts: nav.php containerpage.php and footer.php.

In nav.php, put this:

```
<title><?php
if (isset($subtitle)) {echo "$subtitle";}
else {echo "some other title";}
?>
</title>
```

in container.php, put this:

```
<?php $subtitle = ucwords(str_replace('.php', '', __FILE__)); ?>
```

after that line include your nav.php script:

```
<?php include("nav.php"); ?>
```

This may or may not work depending on your site structure, but this is how I've solved this issue other times.

Comment: nav.php is already included. This is not an option, as it must stay in place.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 6 years old but, I just wanted to give another way to get the file name.

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']
```

or

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
```

Check out the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) on the SERVER global.