# PHP - how can i know the current page name im in it?

Tags: php

PHP - how can i know the current page name im in it?
as example if im in:
http://facebook.com/yoni.php

how can I cut the url and take only the name of the page which is : yoni 
?

Comment: Beware of possible differences between the URL and the actual file name, depending on which you want to find out. Also consider unlikely but possible file names like "my.first.php.class.php" which could cause problems, or even non-.php extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access a lot of information from the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) array.

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

will provide you with the current file name your calling it from, e.g :

example.php

you can then use a plethora of methods to remove the file extention, if you know what it is the easiest would be :

$filename = str_replace(".php","",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

Here's a nice one liner from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201089/1352271) question:

```
$filename = ucfirst(pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME))
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case [`basename()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) is helpful. If you want the name of the URL that is executed try:

```
echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php');
```

Or with your example URL:

```
echo basename('http://facebook.com/yoni.php', '.php'); // outputs "yoni"
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is using the [PHP](http://php.net) [**FILE Magic Constant**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

```
echo __FILE__;
```

And if you want to remove the *.php* extension:

```
echo preg_replace('/\.php$/', '', __FILE__);
```

Answer (score 1):

Items of `$_SERVER` will help you.

```
echo'<pre>',print_r($_SERVER),'</pre>';
```